# Change Partial in Assemble in Each

Tags: gruntjs, yaml, assemble

I just started using assemble and I currently have the following code:

default.hbs:

```
{{#each default.articles}}
    {{> layout  }}
{{/each}}
```

and default.yml:

```
articles:
  - article:
      title: Test 1
      image: image_path
      description: test 1
      reamore: link
      color: FFF
      layout: single

  - article:
      title: Test 2
      image: image_path
      description: test 2
      reamore: link
      color: 000
      layout: double
```

how can i use the layout in the yml data to define which partial to use?

so for example if the layout in yml is double it needs to load the double.hbs partial, and so forth. Is this at all possible? Or am i approaching this all wrong?

Any Help Would Be Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Handlebars you can't dynamically choose a partial, but you can create a helper to do it:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('partial', function (key) {
  var partial = Handlebars.partials[key];
  if (partial) {
    var fn = Handlebars.compile(partial);
    var tmpl = fn(this);
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(tmpl);
  }
  throw new Error('Partial ' + key + ' is not registered with Handlebars');
});
```

Then use the helper:

```
{{#each default.articles}}
    {{partial this.layout}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe layout is a reserved word in YML as you can specify the specific layout for each page. You may want to try renaming the value layout and put the full name of the partial eg double.hbs

I've not managed try it myself so cant be 100% sure.

Comment: `layout` is only used if it's at the root of the front-matter object in pages or if it's set on the main options.